# Referring to a variable in the target file from a class AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, variables, containers

I've researched this all day and I'm stuck! I want to know how to use a variable from a target path to move something. Here is the code:

```
//  Target file
var speed:int = Number(1);
var container:MovieClip = new MovieClip;
var objects:Objects = new Objects();
container.addChild(objects);
```

and

```
//  Class for Objects
package  {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
public class Objects extends MovieClip {        
public function Objects() {
this.x += speed;
trace(this.x);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it, I get an error like this:

```
Objects.as, Line 6 1120: Access of undefined property speed.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most simple way to do it is to pass the `speed` variable to that class. See, classes are like stand alone objects in the space, and they (mostly) don't know about each other, or at least they don't know about the variables that you define in them.

So if you create a class inside another one (`new Objects()`), the most easy way is this:

```
var objects:Objects = new Objects(speed);
```

Then, inside Objects class, you will have:

```
public class Objects extends MovieClip {       

    var _speed:Number;

    public function Objects(speed:Number) {
        _speed = speed; // save it to a local member variable
        this.x += _speed;
        // start working with the local one,
        // which will be accessible in the whole class
    }
```

It's like passing some defined values, so that class can use them. And the class saves them inside itself so it can be used through the whole file (scope).